# Capture groups using DFA-based (linear-time) regular expressions: possible?

Tags: regex, finite-automata, dfa

Is it possible to implement capture groups with DFA-based regular expressions while maintaining a linear time complexity with respect to the input length?

Intuitively I think not, because the subset construction procedure does not know which capture group it may have landed inside, but this is the first time I've realized this may be a potential problem, so I don't know.

Comment: Do you mean just capturing groups, or also matching backreferences?

Comment: @Bergi: Just capture.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to implement capture groups with DFA-based regular expressions while maintaining a linear time complexity with respect to the input length?

Yes - at least when the capture groups are deterministic. Consider the example regex `/a|(a)/`; matching that against the input `"a"` could either produce a captured group or none.

I think that capture groups could be based on a theoretical foundation using [finite state transducers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_transducer), which are like automatons but also may output strings while changing states. You may echo the input, but surround each capture group with parenthesis for example.

> Intuitively I think not, because the subset construction procedure does not know which capture group it may have landed inside, but this is the first time I've realized this may be a potential problem, so I don't know.

Indeed, this is a problem. I think you can solve it by tagging your sets with the capture state, and similarly distinguish the states of your result DFA. You may fail to produce a fully deterministic automaton for regular expression like the above, as [Wikipedia writes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_transducer#Operations_on_finite_state_transducers): "*some non-deterministic transducers do not admit equivalent deterministic transducers*".

However, a modification of the subset construction procedure is possible, see [*Determinization of Transducers*](http://www.let.rug.nl/~vannoord/papers/preds/node22.html). Their algorithm seems to revolve around the following:

> *local ambiguities […] are solved by delaying the outputs as far as needed, until these symbols can be written out deterministically.*

For example, the regexes `/ab|(a)c/` and even `/(a[bc])|ad/` can be resolved into deterministic transducers. Notice that their memory representation may be much larger than if they had no capture groups.

Comment: I'm trying to understand if being deterministic is enough. Would it be possible to make a DFA for a pattern like `x*(a*b)c|x*(a?)(a?)bd`? If you delay the capture until you see a `c` or a `d`, then you've solved the ambiguity problem, but then how do you know which capture was supposed to begin and end where? Is there a way to do this in constant time (and hopefully constant space) with respect to the input length? Perhaps using a stack or something?

Comment: Uh, good question. I haven't delved to deeply into finite state transducers. I think you can solve this by distinguishing capture groups by suffixes, i.e `/x*(a*b)c|x*(a*b)d/` on `abc` should output `(ab0)c` and on `xabd` should output `x(ab1)d`. Those transducers would be determininisable to a rather simple form. Notice that you will always need linear time wrt to the input length; the output (space) would be linear as well but if you optimize and use pointers to the input, you should get linear space wrt the number of capture groups.

Comment: I see. Note that by constant time I meant constant with respect to the input length at each state transition (as there are n state transitions). Regarding the captures, it's something the user specifies, so if I can just change them and recover what the user wanted later quickly.

Comment: Right - but as the output takes linear time, I guess the the time spent for a state transition is amortized to be constant.

Answer (score 2):

My http://github.com/hoehrmann/demo-parselov does this. I do not currently explain the construction on the web page, but suppose you have a grammar like

```
X = "a" B "c"
B = "b"
```

You can turn this regular grammar into a graph with labeled vertices

1. start X
2. "a"
3. start B
4. "b"
5. final B
6. "c"
7. final X

DFA states correspond to sets of these vertices. The first one would consist of vertices 1 and 2, the second one of vertices 3 and 4, then 5 and 6, and finally 7. If you parse the string "abc", you have

1. { offset:   0, vertices: [1, 2] }
2. { offset:   1, vertices: [3, 4] }
3. { offset:   2, vertices: [5, 6] }
4. { offset: EOF, vertices: [7]    }

That is also a graph. You can write out the edges using (offset, vertex) pairs as vertices:

1. (o0, v1) -> (o0, v2)
2. (o0, v2) -> (o1, v3)
3. (o1, v3) -> (o1, v4)
4. ...

Such a graph might contain vertices that do not ultimately reach the final vertex (EOF, v7), but such vertices can be eliminated in O(n) time. If the grammar is ambiguous, a match would be a path through the resulting graph. There may be many possible paths.