# Is there a Stream Wrapping component that edits streams? C#

Tags: c#, stream

I would like to replace some text in a NetworkStream. Ideally by using a Regex to find what I want to replace. The consuming part takes a Stream and I would not like to modify it.

I image something like this?

```
Stream outputStream = new StreamChanger(inputStream, "apple", "banana");
```

Is there an existing component or pattern which can do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962220/apply-a-regex-on-stream

Comment: @spender: Close, but the output is not a stream.

Comment: There's nothing built in that does this.  You'll just have to write your own implementation of `Stream` to do it.

Comment: @Kyle: I'm asking for a component. E.g. a nuget package. I know it's not built in.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to roll your own...some pseudocode:

var changedString = inputStream.read();
changedString = changedString.replace("apple", "banana");

Stream outputStream = new StreamWriter(path);
outputStream.Write(changedString);

Comment: Of course not. I would continue to read from the steam...was just saying as an example, you'd read from it, modify it, and output it to your "output" stream.

Comment: If you want I'll write a StreamChanger class for this, but it may need to be next week : -/